# Django Formsets - How to build a formset correctly and validade it?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using Django 1.4 and I'm struggling with Formsets. I've read the documentation and lots of SO questions. I'm getting out of clues on how they really work.

**- Fomsets should be configured/dclared like this?**

How I've set up the formset in forms.py and views.py.

forms.py: (I've declared a forms.Form)

```
class BicycleAdItemKindPropertyValueForm(forms.Form):
    bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue = forms.ChoiceField()
```

views.py:

```
def submit_ad_view(request):

    # This class is used to make empty formset forms required
    class BicycleAdItemKindPropertyValueFormSet(BaseFormSet):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(BicycleAdItemKindPropertyValueFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for form in self.forms:
                form.empty_permitted = False

        def clean(self):
            pdb.set_trace()  
            for form in self.forms:
                None
            #form.fields['bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue']

    formsetBicycleAdItemKindPropertyValue = formset_factory(BicycleAdItemKindPropertyValueForm, formset=BicycleAdItemKindPropertyValueFormSet)

    if request.method == 'POST':      
        model_main = Main()
        model_main.section = Section.objects.get(pk=request.POST['section'])
        model_main.user = request.user

        model_bicyclead = BicycleAd()
        model_bicyclead.bicycleadtype = BicycleAdType.objects.get(pk=2) #1-Ad Link, 2-Ad Insite. Em principio ficara pre-definido
        model_bicyclead.bicycleaditemkind = BicycleAdItemKind.objects.get(pk=4) 
        model_bicyclead.bicycleadcondition = BicycleAdCondition.objects.get(pk=2)
        model_bicyclead.city = GeonamesLocal.objects.get(pk=4803854)

        # Build the forms
        form_main = MainForm(request.POST, instance = model_main)
        form_bicyclead = BicycleAdForm(request.POST, instance = model_bicyclead)
        form_bicycleadcategory = BicycleAdCategoryForm(request.POST)
        form_bicycleaditemkindselect = BicycleAdItemKindSelectForm(request.POST)
        formset_bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue = formsetBicycleAdItemKindPropertyValue(request.POST)

        #pdb.set_trace()

        if form_main.is_valid() and form_bicyclead.is_valid() and form_bicycleadcategory.is_valid() and form_bicycleaditemkindselect.is_valid() and formset_bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue.is_valid():
            main_f = form_main.save()

            bicyclead_f = form_bicyclead.save(commit=False)
            bicyclead_f.main = main_f
            bicyclead_f.save()

            bicycleadcategory_f = form_bicycleadcategory.save(commit=False, rel_obj=model_bicyclead)  


    else:
        # Build the forms
        form_main = MainForm()
        form_bicyclead = BicycleAdForm()
        form_bicycleadcategory = BicycleAdCategoryForm()
        form_bicycleaditemkindselect = BicycleAdItemKindSelectForm()
        formset_bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue = formsetBicycleAdItemKindPropertyValue()

    return render_to_response('app/submit/submit_ad.html', {'form_main': form_main, 'form_bicyclead': form_bicyclead, 'form_bicycleadcategory': form_bicycleadcategory, 'form_bicycleaditemkindselect': form_bicycleaditemkindselect, 'formset_bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue': formset_bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

These two preceding steps are correct? The formset is declared correctly?

Now, the template. I've declared like this:

sometemplate.html:

```
{{formset_bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue.management_form}}
{{formset_bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue.non_form_errors}}
{{formset_bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue.errors}}
{% for form in formset_bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue.forms %}
<div class="item-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue">
    <label for="{{form.bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue.auto_id}}"></label>
    {{form.bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue}}
</div>
```

With the help of JavaScript, the code will generate something like this:

```
<form action="/submeter/anuncio/" method="post"><div style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" value="3TWjKpqnXG7afZcvF1YmmWcRBKnYqePB" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"></div>
...         
        <div class="someclass">
            <input type="hidden" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="1" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS">
            <input type="hidden" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="0" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS">
            <input type="hidden" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS">
            []
            <div class="item-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue">
                <label for="id_form-0-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue">Some 0</label>
                <select id="id_form-0-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue" name="form-0-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue">
                    ...
                </select>
            </div><div class="item-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue">
                <label for="id_form-1-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue">Some 1</label>
                <select id="id_form-1-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue" name="form-1-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue">
                    ...
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="item-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue">
                <label for="id_form-2-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue">Some 2</label>
                <select id="id_form-2-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue" name="form-2-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue">
                    ...
                </select>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

It is the output correct? Should looks like this?

**- Validation, how to validade a formset?**

Now about the validation. I've a forms.ChoiceField() in my Form

```
class BicycleAdItemKindPropertyValueForm(forms.Form):
    bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue = forms.ChoiceField()
```

I've read that the forms.ChoiceField() should be validated against a list of choices. My question is how can I do this?

**- Some information debugging**

Using the pdb(python debuger) in the clean() I see I got this data:

```
class BicycleAdItemKindPropertyValueFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BicycleAdItemKindPropertyValueFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False

    def clean(self):
        pdb.set_trace()  
        for form in self.forms:
            None
        #form.fields['bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue']
```

Debugging self.data:

```
(Pdb) self.data
<QueryDict: {u'form-1-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue': [u'29'], 
             u'form-2-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue': [u'33'], 
             u'title': [u'adasd'], 
             u'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u''], 
             u'country': [u'42'], 
             u'section': [u'5'], 
             u'item_kind': [u'4'], 
             u'form-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'0'], 
             u'bicycleadcategorytype': [u'3', u'2'], 
             u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'3TWjKpqnXG7afZcvF1YmmWcRBKnYqePB'], 
             u'form-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'3'], 
             u'form-0-bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue': [u'4']}>
```

Debugging self.is_valid():

```
(Pdb) self.is_valid()
False
```

Any clues on how can I validate this formset?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `formset` in the above code is declared correctly. Also, the output generated is how ideally a formset generates it. Regarding validating the form, you can simply do.

```
for form in formset:
    if form.is_valid():
        # If is valid do something here
    else:
        # Do something Else
```

if you want to do the validation stuff on your own, you can override the `clean` method under the `form` class as this method is called by the `is_valid` method.

```
class BicycleAdItemKindPropertyValueForm(forms.Form):
    bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue = forms.ChoiceField()


    def clean(self):
        # Do field validation here.
```

If you are looking to validate and only a single field you can override the `clean_field` method as follows:

```
class BicycleAdItemKindPropertyValueForm(forms.Form):
    bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue = forms.ChoiceField()

    def clean_bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue(self):
        # Do single field validation here.
```

Comment: In the form I've changed to "bicycleaditemkindpropertyvalue = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select())" and now I can clean_<field>. Thanks.